Can どのぐらい or どれぐらい mean "how often"?
A language learning app that I use translates どのぐらい運動しますか? as how often do you exercise?
But a few other sources I looked up do not list how often as a possible translation of どのぐらい
Also, Google Translate translates どのぐらい運動しますか? as how long do you exercise?, and that, to get how often do you exercise?, it should be どのくらいの頻度で運動しますか?.
Which is correct?

It is indeed a bit weird to just say "どのぐらい運動しますか" when asking about "How often~", it is more close to "How much~".
For instance, the answer to "一日にどれぐらい運動すればいいのか？" would be "XX minutes/hours", or "depends on your body weight", instead of a frequency.
頻度 means frequency.
So どのくらいの頻度 is a correct way to say this but it feels more formal.
A natural way to ask "How often~" would be " + 何回ぐらい" or どれぐらいの頻度・どのぐらいの頻度.
Some examples:

毎月何回ぐらい運動していますか？
週に何回ぐらい練習すればいいのか？
どれぐらいの頻度で酒を飲んでますか？

